# List all tables names in Access DB from powershell

Tags: database, powershell, ms-access, adodb

I connect to a access database using.

```
$Conn = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
$Conn.Open("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$FullPath`";Persist Security Info=False;")
```

this works fine.
I can read and update from various tables no problems.
But what I would like to do is list all of the Tables in the database.

I have found this

```
$Conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable([System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid]::tables,$null) | ForEach-Object { 
        $_?
        write-host $_.TABLE_NAME $_.TABLE_TYPE
        $Zones = $_.table_name
    }
```

but I'm getting error messages.

After having looked at a lot of websites, I have realy not found anything.

After listing the tables I would then go on to list the fieds in each table.

I get the following error message.

> ```
> [DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>>     $Conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable([System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid]::tables,$null)
> Les arguments sont de type incorrect, en dehors des limites autorisées ou en conflit les uns avec les autres.
> Au caractère Ligne:1 : 5
> +     $Conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable([System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid]::ta ...
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
> ```

Translation

> Outside of authorised limits.or conflict with each other.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you are getting errors ... don't you think it would help if you posted those errors? [*grin*]

Comment: Sure here is the error message. I just think that I might be on the wrong track with this method which is why I left it out.
Les arguments sont de type incorrect, en dehors des limites autorisées ou en conflit les uns avec les autres.
translation
the arguments are of incorrect types,  Outside of authorised limits.or conflict with each other.

Comment: please add the error message to your Original Post so that your question is all in one place. ///// that does not read like a normal powershell error msg - those usually include the line number and at least part of the line of code involved. are you _sure_ that is a powershell error message?

Comment: I have added the original error message straight from ps into the original post.

Comment: Can you show us exactly what is in variable `$FullPath`? Is there an apostrophe in there maybe? Characters like that can cause trouble in a connection string

Comment: P.S. I have never seen syntax like `$_?` before.. What is that supposed to do?

Comment: Sure PS C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> $FullPath
C:\_Repos\_Scripts\Databases\Parc_CAF061.accdb
As i said I can add edit and delete records, so i d'ont see this as a problem.

Comment: @kbc06 - thanks! [*grin*] now, please add the answer to the 1st question by `Theo` to your post. ///// also, as Theo pointed out, `$_?` IS NOT standard powershell ... so are you sure that is correct? if so, what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

[getoledbschematable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable?view=netframework-4.8):

> ... When you pass values in the array, include empty strings or nulls for array elements that do not contain values. If you pass an empty array to restrictions, all rows (one for each table) are returned in default order. ...

Your code fails when calling `$Conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable`, since you're using the correct `tables` GUID your second parameter might be wrong. Try if using an empty array solves the problem:

```
$emptyArray = @()
$Conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable([System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid]::tables, $emptyArray) | ForEach-Object { 

    write-host $_.TABLE_NAME $_.TABLE_TYPE
    $Zones = $_.table_name
}
```

As stated in the above comments also remove the `$_?` statement, which is no valid PowerShell code.

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks Moerwald for taking the time to look at this. However after trying your solution I still have exactly the same error.